# React Context API ContextValue function not being called

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Nextjs React Typescript application and am trying to set an id (orgId) using the Context API and (later persist to local storage (Windows)) so that it is available across the application and also persists upon refresh. My issue is that the function I have defined in my Context Value to set the orgId (setUpOrgId) is never getting called (have put in debug to test it) even though the UserContextProvider is, hence it is always 0. I have wrapped the  around the main entry point (for Nextjs this is the root level page.tsx)

Here is my UserContextProvider:

```
"use client"
import {createContext, ReactNode, useState} from 'react';
export const UserContext = createContext({
    storedOrgId: 0,
    setUpOrgId: (id:number)=> { console.log("init")},
})
interface UserContextProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}
export default function UserContextProvider({children}:UserContextProviderProps){
    const [orgId, setOrgId] = useState(0);
    console.log("userContext")

    const ctxValue = {
        storedOrgId: orgId,
        setUpOrgId: handleSetUpId
    };

    function handleSetUpId(id: number) {
        console.log("userContext->setUpId")
        setOrgId(id);
    }

    return <UserContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>
        {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
}
```

And here is where I am calling it:

```
"use client"
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

import UserContextProvider, {UserContext} from "@/app/store/userContext";

import {useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  //const [ storedOrgId, setUpOrgId]  = useState(0);
  const {storedOrgId, setUpOrgId} = useContext(UserContext)

  const updateOrgId = () => {
      let newOrgId:number = 7
    console.log("Layout - update org id called with org id:", newOrgId)
          setUpOrgId(newOrgId);
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //  console.log("in useEffect, original orgId:", storedOrgId)
  //   setUpOrgId(10)
  // }, []);




  return (
      // <UserContext.Provider value={{storedOrgId, setUpOrgId}}>

    <html lang="en">
      <body>
      <button onClick={updateOrgId}> Click me</button>

      {children}</body>
    </html>


  );
```

Comment: Is your `RootLayout` wrapped around a `UserContextProvider` ?

Comment: Yes, but see my answer below - Nextjs quirk. Good advice through @klugjo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, this was a Next js quirk.
You need to add a providers component (containing your context providers) to your layout.js. See this advice from Vercel, the inventors of the infuriating Nextjs: https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs